# Specifying percentage width for CSS table cells

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an HTML/CSS-based week calendar using CSS display:table-cell styling on the divs corresponding to each day.  When I specify a percent width for the day divs that is greater than 17%, the divs fills the whole screen as expected (since 7*17% > 100%).

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/huDxZ/1/

However, when I specify a percent width that is 16% or less, the divs behave entirely differently, taking up only part of the page width.

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/DLjnH/

I would like my day divs to each have widths of about 14% so they roughly fill the width of the page and have equal sizes.  Unfortunately, a width of 14% looks even worse.

jsfiddle here:http://jsfiddle.net/YB5bY/

What is causing this unexpected behavior?  Is there any way around it?  I need to explicitly specify widths because eventually I would like the days of the calendar to expand on mouseover.

Please, no solutions involving floats.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

CSS rules percentage values is always relative to the value of the same property of the parent.
Try adding an explicit width to the container:

```
#calendar {
    display: table;
    height:900px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Then you can use `14%` for the ".day" elements.

Answer (score 10):

I cannot tell you the reason but if you force the container `div` to have 100% width the behaviors of the two cases are identical.

```
#calendar {
    display: table;
    height:900px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/DLjnH/1/

Comment: Solves my problem.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Can't mark everyone as having answered, but when I have enough rep I'll upvote you.

Answer (score 6):

Well, I may be crazy, but I would use a table for such a thing...

Not all tables are evil, just the ones used for layout...

Answer (score 5):

Your table cell widths are relative to the parents width, yet the parents with is auto/undefined. Add `width: 100%;` to your `#calendar` css definition for them to behave correctly.

Comment: Works!  Thank you very much.  Can't mark you all as having answered the question but when I have enough rep I'll upvote this.

Comment: Just accept the first to post ;) With simple questions oftentimes people answer simultaneously with the same solution.